# Trying to get a button to open up a calander on ios. Nothing happens when I click button

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, calendar

Attempting to learn programming, I can't create a calander event from pressing a button within my app.

I have put in the privacy setting into the `info.plist`, watched multiple videos and copy-pasted different options.
No errors are coming up, and the button just blinks and nothing happens. 
Could it even be the simulation..?

```
import UIKit
import EventKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func btnAddEventPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let eventStore:EKEventStore = EKEventStore()

        eventStore.requestAccess(to: .event) { (granted, error) in

            if (granted) && (error == nil) {
                print ("granted\(granted)")
                print ("error\(error)")

                let event:EKEvent = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)
                event.title = "Investor research"
                event.startDate = Date()
                event.endDate = Date()
                event.notes = "This is note"
                event.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents

                do {
                    try eventStore.save(event, span: .thisEvent)
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print("error : \(error)")
                }

                print("Save Event")

            } else {
                print("error : \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sSFzcvvs4Oc&t=603s, and expected to be able to schedule an event from pressing a button, but nothing is happening. I may have missed something obvious, but I did everything in the video.

Comment: Check with breakpoints, whether the execution flow comes into granted block when clicking the button.

Answer (score 0):

I have run this code its working fine. Did you add reference to the IBAction from storyboard? If you add the reference correctly it will show "touch up inside" like below image when you right click on your button:[image: Button Reference]
Did you add "Privacy - Calendars Usage Description" correctly in Info.plist ? If this added correctly then you will get a permission popup for Calendar usage permission(press ok to that popup). 
If all these things are ok then check log it should print these 3 line per button click:

```
grantedtrue
errornil
Save Event
```

If the log print these lines, then check the default calendar app of the simulator or phone where you run your application. It will show event added in current day when you run the application in this case it will be 26 June.

**According to your current code clicking the button will not open the calendar it will add event to the calendar**

If you want to show added event  by opening calendar application  immediately after saving, then add these lines after print("Save Event") :

```
 let interval = event.startDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
 let url = URL(string: "calshow:\(interval)")
 if let calendarUrl = url {
                if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(calendarUrl, options: [:],
                                              completionHandler: {
                                                (success) in

                    })
                } else {
                    UIApplication.shared.openURL(calendarUrl)

                }
            }
```